# What exactly is induced electric field, Is it present only in conducting loops?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

In my textbook it is written that : ***The presence of a conducting loop is not necessary to have an induced electric field. As long as $\vec B$  keeps changing, the electric field is present. If a loop is there, the free electrons start drifting and consequently an induced current results.*** Does that mean that the induced electric field can be just anywhere ? How is it possibe ?  Thank you for reading such a long question, thanks for even reading it.

Comment: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/778085/nature-of-faraday-induced-electric-fields/778092?noredirect=1#comment1747537_778092

Comment: @hyportnex, can you tell the answer because that question do not cover every question of mine. Please it is a humble request.

Comment: This *phys.stack* forum prefers one question per post, and you have several. It may or may not help you but answer was directed to one issue: how is the loop integral of the induced field related to flux rate. If that does not answer your questions/doubts then I suggest that you concentrate on one and ask it again by editing this post of yours.

Comment: Did that @hyportnex

Comment: Yes the induced field can be anywhere except where an electric field is not allowed to be at all, for example the *inside* of an ideal conductor having infinite conductivity.  But the induced electric field can penetrate the inside of a real metal, think of eddy currents in a transformer.

Comment: Never forget: Faraday's law does not describe how the electromagnetic field acts on matter (currents, charges, etc.), instead you should always think of it as that it shows how the two "ingredients" of the *electromagnetic field*, namely, the electric field intensity and the magnetic field intensity are *related* mathematically to each other. Despite the usual verbiage written in most textbooks, this is not a causal relationship, it is rather a coexistence relationship. If you want to know what the E&M field does to currents or charges, etc., you have to invoke Lorentz's force law.

Comment: @Farcher Sir, according to me because the induced electric field is closed, electrons cannot move opposite to electric field because if they move opposite to closed induced electric field then after a time later they will end up at a point where they are along this direction of induced electric field (SORRY for bad narration i cannot add a image)

Comment: When there is a complete electrical circuit the electrons circulate around the circuit under the influence of the induced electric field.